# Кеширование строки в Андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет. С сервера приходит json с данными. Может быть очень большая строка. Мне нужно при каждой загрузки сохранять эти строки чтобы после если подключения к интернету нет выводились последние сохраненные публикации. Как бы вы поступили на моем месте? Как бы вы сохраняли?

Comment: Мало деталей чтобы сказать точно. Можно или в файл записать или в префы или в БД

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а в префы большую строку можно вместить? Просто приходить очень большая строка

Comment: Тогда лучше в файл

Comment: @ЮрийСПб наверно так и сделаю

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `okhttp3.Cache` при работе через `Retrofit`.
Пример запроса с кэшированием:

```
    private void loadJSON() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(new ResponseCacheInterceptor());
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new OfflineResponseCacheInterceptor());
    httpClient.cache(new Cache(new File(MyApplication.getMyApplicationInstance()
            .getCacheDir(), "ResponsesCache"), 10 * 1024 * 1024));
    httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

    ApiInterface request = ApiClient.getClient(httpClient).create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<NewsResponse> call = request.getHeadlines(source, Constants.API_KEY);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull retrofit2.Call<NewsResponse> call,
                               @NonNull Response<NewsResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                articles.clear();
                articles.addAll(response.body().getArticles());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
        }
```

Comment: Не хочется возится с okhttpCache ибо никогда не пользовался. Сделаю как юрий сказал сохраню в файл. Всем спасибо